# How to use getline to read from a file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I could use your help on this problem. I have a file that contains this:

```
1x+1y+1z=5
2x+3y+5z=8
4x+0y+5z=2
```

I must store that into a string. Once stored the output should be this:

```
1x+1y+1z=5
a=1 b=1 c=1 d=5
2x+3y+5z=8
a=2 b=3 c=5 d=8
4x+0y+5z=2
a=4 b=0 c=5 d=2
```

This is the code I have, however it is not outputting anything. Can anybody help me? It gives me an error on line 19 but I don't know how to fix it. The error states "no matching function for call."

> |19|error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::basic_ifstream::getline(std::string [10], int)'|
>   |22|error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::basic_istringstream::basic_istringstream(std::string
>   [10])'|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("matrix.txt");

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Could not open input file\n";
        return 1;
    }


    for (string line[10]; file.getline(line, 10); )
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
        istringstream ss(line);

        double a, b, c, d;
        char x, y, z, eq;

        if (ss >> a >> x >> b >> y >> c >> z >> eq >> d)
        {
            if (x == 'x' && y == 'y' && z == 'z' && eq == '=')
            {
                cout << "a = " << a
                     << "  b = " << b
                     << "  c = " << c
                     << "  d = " << d << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "parse error 2\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "parse error 1\n";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Whenever asking "Why doesn't this code work" please provide all errors you get when compiling/running

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), never use it.

Comment: `for (string line[10]; file.getline(line, 10); )` This line looks highly suspicious to me.

Comment: Post the **exact** error you receive from the compiler character-for-character in a code block, not a re-phrased or a shortened one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes.

**Mistake no. 1**

You cannot and should not declare `string line[10]`. You also should not use a `for` loop. Here is a classic implementation of reading string by string from a stream:

```
string line;
while (file >> line) {
  ... // do stuff
}
```

**Mistake no. 2**

Your numbers are ints, not doubles, so you should use:

```
int a, b, c, d;
```

**Saving values into an array**

First of all, let me say, that there is no good reason to use raw arrays. You should always prefer using standard ADTs, such as the std::vector.

In this scenario, you should not read the value right into the vector, since the value may be ill-formed.

Instead follow this sequence:

```
vector<string> lines;
string line;
while (file >> line) {
  ... // do stuff

  if (successful)
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Comment: But I want to store the line into an array.

Comment: @compscistudent, updated the answer to add lines to a vector

Comment: The thing is I still cannot use vectors, and I must store into an array to manipulate the numbers with pointers

Comment: @compscistudent, are you sure you want an array of `string`s? maybe you should use an array of `char`s? At least that will make sense in terms of manipulating numbers with pointers...

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to read a file and insert into an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_LINES = 100;

int main() {
    std::string strArray[MAX_LINES];
    fstream newFile;
    newFile.open("matrix.txt", ios::in); //open a file to perform read operation
    if (newFile.is_open()) {   //checking whether the file is open
        string tp;
        for (int counter = 0; getline(newFile, tp); counter++) { // get new line
            strArray[counter] = tp; // read into string array
            cout << tp << "\n"; //print the string
        }
        newFile.close(); //close the file object.
    }
    return 0;
}
```